# Can someone explain how I am to access this array? (image processing program)

Tags: c++

I am working on the implementation of functions for an already written image processing program. I am given explanations of functions, but not sure how they are designating pixels of the image.

In this case, I need to `flip the image horizontally, i.e., rotates 180 degrees around the vertical axis`

Is this what makes the "image" i am to flip?

```
    void Image::createImage(int width_x, int height_y)
{
    width = width_x;
    height = height_y;
    if (pixelData!=NULL)
        freePixelData();
    if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    pixelData = new Color* [width];  // array of Pixel*
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        pixelData[x] = new Color [height];  // this is 2nd dimension of pixelData
    }
}
```

I do not know if all the functions I have written are correct.
Also, the `Image` class calls on a `Color` class

So to re-ask: what am I "flipping" here?

Prototype for function is:

```
void flipLeftRight();
```

As there is no input into the function, and I am told it modifies pixelData, how do I flip left to right?

Comment: This is way to much code. Few people will take the time to look that through. Try to make your question more specific and then please post the code directly here.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: I wasn't sure what people needed to understand what I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

A quick in place flip.  Untested, but the idea is there.

void flipHorizontal(u8 *image, u32 width, u32 height)
{
    for(int i=0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < width/2; j++)
        {
            int sourceIndex = i * width + j;
            int destIndex = (i+1) * width - j - 1;
            image[sourceIndex] ^= image[destIndex];
            image[destIndex] ^= image[sourceIndex];
            image[sourceIndex] ^= image[destIndex];
        }
    }
}

Comment: I would upvote you except you used the XOR swap - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm.

Comment: Hadn't seen that article before.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: Your code as written won't work against the `pixelData` array as initialized above.  The `Color` components in the original post aren't allocated contiguously - you *have* to use double-indirection to access each item.

Comment: as I understand, the 2dim array is 'pixelData[x][y]', and this is what i am to modify in my function, correct?

Answer (score 0):

well, the simplest approach would be to read it 1 row at a time into a temporary buffer the same size as 1 row.

Then you could use something like `std::reverse` on the temporary buffer and write it back.

You could also do it in place, but this is the simplest approach.

**EDIT**: what i;ve described is a mirror, not a flip, to mirror you also need to reverse the order of the rows. Nothing too bad, to do that I would create a buffer the same size as the image, copy the image and then write it back with the coordinates adjusted. Something like `y = height - x` and `x = width - x`.